# Date format added to combo box via VBA is different when added

Tags: excel, vba

I have a peculiar problem at the moment. I have a bunch of dates in column A within the format of dd/mm/yyyy.

I have some VBA that populates the combox:

```
Sub fillCombo()
With Sheet4.WeekComboBox
    .AddItem Cells(3, 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

In cell 3,1 I have date 10/04/2022. But when the value of this cell is added into the combo box it comes out in the format of 04/10/2022 (mm/dd/yyyy) and I'm not really sure why.

Thanks all.

Comment: Just try forcing it: `.AddItem Format(Cells(3, 1), "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: @Simon Thanks that worked well. That was painfully obvious D: